# Docbook: configuring the name of the toc file?

Tags: xslt, docbook

From a Docbook document, I apply an xslt stylesheet that with xsltproc is able to produce the table of content file along with files per chapters.

I would like to know if there is a way to specify the name of the generated toc file because what I have so far is bk01-toc.html and I would like this to be generated as another name.

Any thoughts?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible (but a little cumbersome). You need to customize two fairly large named templates in the chunk-common.xsl stylesheet module (part of DocBook XSL):

1. **make.lots** (outputs the TOC file [if the `chunk.tocs.and.lots` parameter is set])

   Here you need to customize the `<xsl:with-param name="filename">` element that contains `<xsl:text>-toc</xsl:text>`.
2. **footer.navigation** (generates a link to the TOC file in the footer of HTML chunks)

   Customize the `<xsl:attribute name="href">` element that contains `<xsl:text>-toc</xsl:text>`.